# Methods for integral calculation

Tags: integration

I have to calculate the following integral:

$
 \int_{0}^{\infty} {{e^{-\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}} e^{-k x}} dx},
$

where $a, b, c$ and $k$ are all real positive numbers.

I tried to solve it by part integration and substitution but It doesn't work.
Can you please give me any indication or method to try.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe complete the square and use a trigonometric substitution? That's the first thing that came to me, though I haven't yet worked it out.

Comment: yes, that seems useful, I will try it, thank you

Comment: I doubt very much that there will be a known closed form of this, but I'm happy if I'm proved wrong.

Comment: can I just replace the total exponential by its Taylor series representation, obtaining a simpler form and then calculating the integral after proving a possible inversion between the integral and the infinite sum?